# aspectj pointcut and advice for single call following construction of an instance

Tags: java, constructor, aspectj, pointcut

Based on my own experimentation and the documentation here: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.html#q:initializationjoinpoints

This:

```
public class Init {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Test(); 
    } 
}

@Inherited
@interface MyAnnotation {}

@MyAnnotation
class Super {}

class Test extends Super {
    Test() {}
}
```

Will result in this:

```
  <constructor-call sig="Test()" >
    <staticinitialization sig="Super._init_" />
    <staticinitialization sig="Test._init_" />
    <initialization sig="Super()" >
      <instanceinitializer-execution sig="Super._init_" />
      <constructor-execution sig="Super()" />
    </initialization>
    <initialization sig="Test()" >
      <instanceinitializer-execution sig="Test._init_" />
      <constructor-execution sig="Test()" />
    </initialization>
  </constructor-call>
```

I am trying to create an advice based on a pointcut so that I can perform action on an instance after it has been completely constructed, regardless whether it is of type Super or of type Test.

I have tried this:

```
pointcut initializedCall(): initialization((@MyAnnotation *).new(..));

after(Super s) returning: this(s) && initializedCall() {
    System.out.println("after initialization via aspect");
}
```

but it gets called twice when creating an instance of Test.  Once after Super is initialized, and then again after Test is initialized.

I have tried this:

```
pointcut constructorExecution(): execution((@MyAnnotation *).new(..));

after(Super s) returning : target(s) && constructorExecution() {
    System.out.println("after constructor execution via aspect");
}
```

And it too gets called twice which creating an instance of Test, same as above.

Finally, I have tried this:

```
pointcut constructorCall(): call((@AutowiredClass *).new(..));

after(): constructorCall() {
    System.out.println("after constructor call via aspect");
}
```

Which works great, as it only gets called once, but I can't use target() on it to get a reference to the newly created instance, just as described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.html#q:adviseconstructors).

Is there any way to execute at the same time as the last, but also get a reference to the instance?  Or is there a way to tell if the aspect is going to fire again so I can wait until the last time?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I also need this to work with reflection, as I am serializing and deserializing the classes to/from json and want to ensure code gets executed appropriately following construction during deserialization.

Comment: I've found *a* solution, though it isn't very clean...  during the instialization handler, I can check to see if the class of 'this' is the same as the class of thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation().getWithintype(), and if they match, I know the last constructor has been initialized.  Please chime in if you know a better or cleaner way.

Comment: Received a down vote.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to weave the calling code and not just the executing one, you can use the `call()` pointcut, but you need an `around()` advice instead of `after()` in order to bind the created object to a variable and print it or do anything else with it:

```
import de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation;

public aspect ObjectConstructionInterceptor {
    pointcut constructorCall(): call((@MyAnnotation *).new(..));

    Object around() : constructorCall() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
        Object createdObject = proceed();
        System.out.println("Created object = " + createdObject);
        return createdObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it, unfortunately, did not work for my purposes.  I need the advice to execute even if the constructor is called via reflection, and the around() doesn't get called in that case.

Comment: Don't you think it is a bit unfair to let others work out solutions for you and then not accept them by mentioning things which were never part of the original question? Nowhere here you even mention the word "reflection". It is really a waste of time trying to help you. It feels like a slap in the face.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that the aspects behaved differently w/ respect to reflection.  I guess if I knew everything about aspect programming, I wouldn't be asking questions here, would I?